# get values from Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have used a viewpager for gallery.but I cant access the controls inside the viewpager which are inflated. I cant get the values from the viewpager widget. For example in gallery widget I have access to the controls inside like this :

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int arg2, long arg3) {
    TextView tvid = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tvid);
    getrowlist = (String) tvid.getText();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
});
```

I have tried everything to access this widgets controls I also have tried “setOnPageChangeListener” ‘s closest event:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)viewPager.findViewById(R.id.country);
    System.out.println(tv.gettext()(;
}
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
}
});
```

But also in this matter by changing the pages not always it returns a value.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you inflated inside your viewpager, if you are using fragments then you have to apply your clicklistener of your fragments. IMHO you should clearly specify what is that you want to achieve ?

Comment: I don’t use fragment
In my application I use the following example:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

the problem is that I should access  the value of the widget which is related to product ID in the viewpager to calculate on it.

Comment: In such a case you have to use `getItem` function of your pageradapter.

Comment: I have use PagerAdapter in my program. Isn’t  getItem in PagerAdapter
But it is in FragmentPagerAdapter, but I have not used the Fragment

Comment: so use `getItemPosition` that would do the same in case of `PagerAdapter`

Comment: I just want to access widget value and not it’s position in addition  the output of the  getItemPosition in PagerAdapter is integer type and the getitem output in FragmentPagerAdapter is fragment. In my opinion the getitem is not equal to getitemposition.

Comment: @user2261110 Hey I am middle of the same problem. How did you Solved it??? Can you help me out??